# jQuery selector multiple classes under a single class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Given the following HTML,

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
    <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

How would I write an .on event selector that will fire for b and c, but not d?

I've tried:

```
$(document).on("click", ".a .b.c", function () { 
    alert('test');
 });
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try ``on("click", ".a .b, .a .c", function () ...``

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to specifically target `.b` and `.c` under `.a`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".a .b, .a .c", function () { 
    alert('test');
 });
```

Comment: That did it!  I knew it was something simple.  Thanks!